# Mac/Xcode - pod install, pod init, pod... all error "bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Tags: ruby, xcode, cocoapods, homebrew

I see many, many instances of similar issues related to recent Mac OS/xCode updates with multitudes of proposed solutions that seem to work as often as not. So far, none have worked for me. Here's what i'm seeing.

I have a long-standing xCode project with cocoapods. A second developer did some updates on a different system which resulted in build errors reading:

```
"The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation."
```

When I use the terminal to attempt "pod init, pod update, pod install, pod deintegrate etc... I get:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The actual Ruby version that exists on my machine is 2.6, not 2.3

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby:
```

There is no folder on my machine located at

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby:
```

`$ which ruby` says: `/usr/bin/ruby`
That file does exist.

Multiple sources say that ruby installed by HOMEBREW would be found at:

```
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
```

There is currently no alias for Ruby in that location.
/usr/local/opt is full of folder aliases but there is no "ruby" alias

I've deleted & reinstalled the xCode commandline tools but when I try to do basically anything with homebrew (brew doctor, brew update, brew upgrade etc...)I get errors like this:

```
Mainframe:~ username$ brew -v
Homebrew 0.9.5
Mainframe:~ username$ brew upgrade
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:31:in `<main>'
    3: from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:15:in `version'
    2: from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:15:in `new'
    1: from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/version.rb:24:in `initialize'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/version.rb:176:in `initialize': Version value must be a string (TypeError)
```

All of this started (apparently) because something is different on the other developers machine. I've been chasing this issue around in circles for days and getting nowhere.

Having done all of this, I'm thinking the problem lies somewhere back at the beginning with my machine looking for a Ruby 2.3 that does not exist rather than the 2.6 that DOES exist but I have no clue how to tell for sure or how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> The actual Ruby version that exists on my machine

Actually, that’s the source of the problem. Under no circumstances should you use the system ruby! Use rbenv to take control of your ruby versions.

```
sudo gem install ...
```

Blap! Game over, thank you for playing. The fact that you have to say sudo is a major giveaway. This will lead to huge trouble later. Again, this is because you’re using the evil system ruby. This was always wrong. It is not intended for public use! Use rbenv and never say `sudo` again.

Comment: See https://www.biteinteractive.com/how-to-get-started-with-pods/

Comment: Hey Matt, nice name. I'm Matt. Thanks for the tip. Looks like a great tutorial. I'm working through my options to a version that I'll have control over. The specific cause of the problem was the configuration (pod) file pointing to a non-existent, old version of system Ruby. None of the standard procedures to deintegrate or reinstall the pods were working because Ruby 2.3 did not exist. Updating Homebrew has not gone smoothly for me either so I  backed up to the root of the problem for now. The solution below works & from what I'm reading, I think a lot of people may have this same issue.

Comment: I like your advice not to use Sudo... The problem is that CocoaPods themselves recommend using the standard Ruby.... they say to use that "unless you know what you're doing". I mean given that even experienced devs have to fumble through this... I'd say that's a vote from CocoaPods for the standard Ruby. Why can't we get the standard Ruby to work with this? https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html

Comment: @BradleyThomas All the more reason not to use CocoaPods in the first place. :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Hack the pod file

Short version:
1.) Open the file at usr/local/bin/pod
2.) Change 2.3 to 2.6 in the top line

Long version:

There is an executable file located at: usr/local/bin/pod
The contents are as follows:

```
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'cocoapods' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0.a"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/ and Gem::Version.correct?($1) then
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

load Gem.bin_path('cocoapods', 'pod', version)
```

I opened the file at: `usr/local/bin/pod`
and edited the first line to change 2.3 to 2.6.

This had some effect. Now if I cd into my xcode project and try to run "pod update" I get a different error.

```
Mainframe:graffwriter username$ pod update
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin20/rbconfig.rb:229: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/pilotrase/bin/FDK/Tools/osx in PATH, mode 040777
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
    1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:262:in `bin_path'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem cocoapods (>= 0.a) with executable pod (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

The pods now seem to be missing...

I ran:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

It seems to have worked.

I ran:

```
pod update
```

It seems to have worked.

I opened the xCode project and ran a build. The error no longer occurred and the build succeeded.